# Get Perforce submitted changelist number in the context of gitlab-runner CI job execution

Tags: continuous-integration, environment-variables, perforce, changelist, gitswarm

Recently started to get into GitSwarm and currently stuck on the possibility to use the corresponding Perforce submitted changelist number when the continuous integration job has been executed after the `git push` delivery (to align with company's apps builds numbering policy).

Is there a simple way to do this (probably just some [environment variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) to use in `.gitlab-ci.yml`, but e.g. **CI_COMMIT_SHA** does not look friendly at all) or I have to use `p4` command execution explicitly (somewhere in the `script:` section of the job description) to obtain the revision?

And, by the way, what are the alternatives in GitSwarm to achieve the unique numbering of builds (I mean so that, for example, my iOS or Android app bundle is numbered as **Version="1.0", Build="123456"**, where "1.0" is taken from my project files, while "123456" is what I'm interested in to represent the exact code baseline on which the app was assembled)?

Thanks in advance!